# Creating an "One Word" URL Reference

Tags: server, dns

Our Business Intelligence group wants to make something really simple for the end-user population: a one-word URL link to our web-based reporting area.  I am not sure how, or if it is even possible to make this work.  Below is a redacted version of the real URL:

```
http://demo.freshlink.local/reports
```

Instead of fully specifying that real URL what they are requesting is that we somehow make the single word: `freshlink` point to that same location as in  `http://freshlink`

Their goal is that the end-user could simply type `freshlink` in the address bar of the browser and it would go to `http://demo.freshlink.local/reports`.

Anyone know if this is possible and if so how would we do it?  I have been considering all angles as it relates to DNS and the way URLs and browsers work and I cannot think of a way to make this happen myself.

I have configured DNS server in Ubuntu Linux (BIND). "example.com" And I have CNAME Record. I pointed the CNAME record to demo.example.com demo IN CNAME XXXXXXXX.XXXXX.YYYYY.com In the browser if I hit "demo.example.com", it’s working fine. But our target URL is `http://demo`.

Comment: You can achieve this in your company network where you can add DNS records. To make it work for the outer world, you’d need to get a [top-level domain](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Top-level_domain). Anyway, this seems to be unrelated to Ubuntu. It would only be related if your question was how to add the DNS record on your company’s DNS server which is running Ubuntu.

Comment: Hey hi, thanks for the reply, since my DNS server is in ubuntu OS, I hope somebody can help me in creating a DNS records to solve this issue. I hope this page can solve my query.

Comment: `http://freshlink.com/` is already used by someone else. Your first step and it is difficult is find one word that isn't already registered. Then your second step is to register that word.

Comment: I have configured dns server in ubuntu linux (BIND). "example.com"

And I have CNAME Record. I pointed the CNAME record to demo.example.com

demo IN CNAME XXXXXXXX.XXXXX.YYYYY.com

In browser if I hit "demo.example.com", Its working fine.

But our target URL is http://demo

So I want to use "http://demo" instead of "http://demo.example.com"

Kindly help me on this.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Local DNS server](https://askubuntu.com/questions/921149/local-dns-server). Related on [unix.se]: [How to make a machine accessible from the LAN using its hostname](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/16890/how-to-make-a-machine-accessible-from-the-lan-using-its-hostname)